# onfinish event listeners in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, event-listener

Hey guys this is a snippet of my current code. I want to know how to add an "onFinish or Finished" event listener to this code.

this is the setStage function

```
    function setStage($section)
    {

    switch($section)
    {
        case "about":
            if (stageSet == true)
            {
                resetStage();
            }
            $("#one").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#two").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#three").animate({ height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#four").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#five").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            stageSet = true;
            break;
        case "portfolio":
            if (stageSet == true)
            {
                resetStage();
            }
            $("#one").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#two").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#three").animate({ height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#four").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#five").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            stageSet = true;
            break;
        case "contact":
            if (stageSet == true)
            {
                resetStage();
            };
            $("#one").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#two").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#three").animate({ height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#four").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#five").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            stageSet = true;
            break;
        case "resume":
            if (stageSet == true)
            {
                resetStage();
            }
            $("#one").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#two").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#three").animate({ height: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#four").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            $("#five").animate({ width: "+=30"}, 1000);
            stageSet = true;
            break;
        default:
            alert('not a valid section');
            break;
        }
    }
```

the animations inside each case will be unique, but I just made the animations identical for now. Below is what happens on the click. What I need it to do is apply a class "off" to each nav, which it does, and then when setStage is finished I need it to take off the class

```
$(".nav-btn").click(function()
{
    var section = $(this).attr("title");
    //turn off pointer for obsessive clickers
    $(".nav-btn").addClass("off");

    onComplete: function(setStage(section)
    {
        $(".nav-btn").removeClass("off");
    });
});
```

this of course doesn't work. The setStage function works great, what I want to do is remove the class when the function finishes. I checked the api event section on the jquery site and didn't see anything that would suffice, maybe I'm just not looking hard enough. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/  or maybe I'm looking in the wrong section all together. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance for assisting me in my noobness.

Comment: Remove what class, when what function finishes? What does `setStage` do?

Comment: there you go Matt, i need it to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var removeClass = function() {
    $(this).removeClass("off");
}


    function setStage($section)
{

switch($section)
{
    case "about":
    case "portfolio":
    case "resume":    // and so on

        if (stageSet == true)
        {
            resetStage();
        }
        $("#one").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000, removeClass );
        $("#two").animate({ width: "+=30", height: "+=30"}, 1000, removeClass);
        $("#three").animate({ height: "+=30"}, 1000, removeClass);
```

Comment: i tried this, it doesn't wait for setStage() to finish before removing the classes.

Comment: that is because .animate() executes asynchronously. You have to define a function which removes that class and pass it as a callback to .animate(). I'll edit answer to show

Comment: thanks so much, now my question is can I add that callback to my setStage function or do I have to add it into the end of each animate function? I would really like it to just execute after each case if possible. I tried placing it outside the case loop, but it didn't work.

Comment: it's much better add it only to the last call of .animate() method in each case block, but then you have to use $(".nav-btn").removeClass("off");
instead of $(this).removeClass("off");
 as I've edited my answer

Comment: and I've noticed that your code is duplicated in each case block. Why ain't you using grouping of case statements?

Comment: I changed each case to be a certain animation pattern